# PHP modulo foreach condition display only even numbers of array

Tags: php, arrays, modulo

I'm new to PHP and taking a class in it and I have an assignment to return only even numbers from an array. From the php.net website modulo should work for this but it doesn't seem to be returning anything. What is wrong with this code?

```
<?php
        // colors Array
        $colors = array(
            0 => "Red",
            1 => "Pink",
            2 => "Blue",
            3 => "Baby Blue",
            4 => "Green",
            5 => "Lime",
            6 => "Black",
            7 => "Grey",
            8 => "Purple",
            9 => "Violet"
        );

        // Repeat Part 1 above, but only display the solid colors
        krsort($colors);
        // For Each item in array, Loop through the colors of the array and display the index number and color name.
        foreach($colors as $key => $color){
            if($key % == 2)
                echo "<p class='sub-heading'>Color: {$key}: is {$color}</p>";

        } // end forEach loop
        ?>
```

Comment: Try `$key % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Just remember modulo is the remainder after division, 0 will be an even number 1 would be odd etc..

Comment: @Alex '0 me'? What do you mean?

Btw, I made an answer for this, you may accept the answer if you think it's the right answer.

Comment: Yes your answer is right Benno, just wanted to point out to jmccommas how modulo works :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of using the modulo operator to get the desired result: `$key % 2 === 0`

So, example of a for loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value % 2 === 0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```